# Understanding Spikeslab Output

Tags: r, bayesian-networks

I'm using spikeslab for the first time, but don't understand what the output means. It was suggested to me that I use it to tell which variables my dependent variable is most correlated to, in a ranked order. 
Particuarly, what is "bma" bma.scale" "gnet" and "gnet.scale"? I also don't understand how to read the corresponding plot to the model.Thanks for any help!

For example, this is one of the models I created using spikeslab, with its output:

```
model2_ss <-spikeslab(Risk_Pct ~ Race
+                    +hispanic
+                    +Born_In_US
+                    +Highest_Education
+                    +Marital_Status
+                    , na.rm = TRUE, data = LabeledData)
> model2_ss
------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Variable selection method     : AIC 
Big p small n                 : FALSE 
Screen variables              : FALSE 
Fast processing               : TRUE 
Sample size                   : 26 
No. predictors                : 5 
No. burn-in values            : 500 
No. sampled values            : 500 
Estimated mse                 : 0.4299 
Model size                    : 3 


---> Top variables:
                bma      gnet     bma.scale     gnet.scale
Marital_Status  0.516     0.516     0.319         0.319
Born_In_US      -0.469    -0.447    -0.440       -0.419
Race            0.458     0.421     0.926         0.851
```

[image: Plot of model2_ss]

Answer (score 1):

BMA is "Bayesian Model Averaged". GNET is "Generalized Elastic Net".

Have you tried reading the Ishwaran and Rao papers as mentioned in the documentation for `spikeslab`?  There's an article in the R Journal as well that might be worth reading too: https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Ishwaran~et~al.pdf - no sense duplicating it all here.